# How to validate authorized form submission

Tags: jsp, servlets, architecture, authorization

Generally we use captcha to validate form is not submitted by robot or script.
But in our application we can not is captcha everywhere..

What strategy can be used to validate that request is comming from our own form and is not a duplicated/assembled form?

Specially for jsp/servlet. Although I am talking about strategy and not more concern about technology.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to embed some security token  as request parameter in html form. You can use various algorithm to generate security token. Like generate security token based on some random number alongwith session id so that if some how hacker steals session also, he wont be able to access resource in your application

Comment: Yes I thought about it. But once I am logged in, I can make a script which will use same session and request for the page, retrieve access token from it and use it to query further.. even by calling URL scripts can retrieve cookies too. And can use them to duplicate our form requests... can you give me something more?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are worried about a [Cross-site Request Forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attack (CSRF).

If that is the case, there are frameworks that exist to include a random token in each form as a hidden field that gets validated by the server.  I would start looking for CSRF protection approaches for your specific platform.

Comment: May be frameworks like JSF does something similar. But those fields can be retrieved in scripts, right? Then it can be sent with request back. How to countermeasures it? Sorry but I ask lot of questions, but I want to understand it deeply. How can I do it without using frameworks?

Comment: The only way to prevent the possible submission via script is to require authentication in your application.  Even then, someone who can validly authenticate could still script a submission if they knew what they were doing.
CSRF tokens are there to slow the process down and deter the simple scripter, since a script would have to load the page fresh each time to get a new valid CSRF token.

Why are you so concerned about a form being submitted via script?  If you want to prevent robots from spamming it, a CAPCHA is really what you need.

Comment: I agree about CAPTCHA, but we can bother upset to pas s through it everywhere in the site..I am working on a strategy, I will post it here..

Answer (score 2):

Two more possibilities:

1. You could add a honeypot input field to your form which you have made invisible to human users with a CSS rule - `display:none`.  Give the input field a name like 'email'. You can verify on the server-side that this field is blank since humans won't see it. Reject any submission that contains a value in that field since a robot will likely supply a fake email address in your honeypot field.
2. You could render a hidden timestamp field in your form when the .jsp renders. Examine that returned timestamp when the form is submitted. Humans will normally take a few seconds to read the form and fill out each field.  A robot submission would be quite fast from the time the form is requested to the time the bot makes the POST submission.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.(1) someone who wants to duplicate your request will first analyse your real request on network and that will reveal that email is not sent,and can generate script accordingly. (2) bit good but is not accurate, is like 50-50 case

Answer (score 1):

This might be somewhat complicated, but you could design an algorithm that changes a token based on ticks from timestamps. So, the user is issued a token and the application notes the time as well. The algorithm then alters the token based on a defined (secret) pattern. Then when the form is submitted you analyze the token and the timestamp delta between initial log in and when someone form submission to ensure 2 things. 1. That your delta is humanly possible. And 2. That the pattern matches the between the token and the timestamp.

Comment: Very close to what I am searching.. can you go in bit detail please?

Comment: Start with a defined (secretive) pattern of characters, then when someone logs is you record the timestamp and issue a token. You then modify this token by factors based on the above pattern per each "tick" (minute, hour, second, etc) that the person is logged in for. Then when this person submits the form, you grab the token that you've issued to them as well as the modified version you've recorded and compare the 2 against both the pattern and the timestamp delta from when the person logged in to when they submitted to the form

Answer (score 0):

My humble opinion is that you are over analyzing this. Unfortunately, no solution is going to be 100% fool proof. Even captchas are not 100% reliable and hacks for them are publicly available. Even the sound based captchas have been broken into. The answers posted by others here are good options to start with. Start with them, and see how many bad requests get filtered out. If they filter out 90% of the bad requests, you just need to analyze and learn the patterns of the rest of the 10% and put in point solutions (IP filtering, throttling etc) which will fix those.

You can't prevent 100% of bad requests hitting your server 100% of the time. You just do your best to prevent them and have a plan to mitigate the damage.

Comment: I know 100% is not possible, and answers posted above are not bad, but can they filter 90% of bad requests or hacks?? NO. Are big companies doing only what is answered above?? NO. So those are not answers what satisfy me. And I know that 1 technique can't prevent all hacks, but I am searching for bunch of techniques which can be applied. And yes ipfiltering is one of them, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that these methods will not prevent 90% of attacks? You dont know that until you try it. Big companies spent a lot of time and money to implement security checks. They constantly iterate over multiple solutions over multiple projects. They hire independent security companies to audit their systems. If you want a security system which will be on par with what a big company has, you need to invest more money/time/resources. Stackoverflow is certainly not the place for getting that kind of advice.

Comment: Thanks, :) (1) if you are a little aware about what kind of attacks are possible, then you yourself can estimate percent of attacks can be prevented. (2) yes big companies are spending money and time on them. Tell me if you want develop a software then will you start making a programing language first? Or will you use existing one?? :). If industruly is using something then why to spend time on it again? Why can't we start using them and go ahead?? (3) This is not my answer and I am trying to get it. So if you do not have answer then please no need to waste others time. Thanks again..

Comment: @Pratik why don't just see how a Java Web Framework handles this? For example, JSF and Spring MVC. They're both open source.